# Is there a way to SUMIFS based on a output range condition?

Tags: google-sheets, filter, match, google-sheets-formula, google-sheets-query

The practical example is: I need to sum the total amount of time worked on a week for specific roles (engineer, etc..) within the company.
What I need is to sum a column of values only if the name on the left has a specific role. I could put that role on a column next to the name, but as I would like to keep a history of employee promotion, the role is on a similar week basis table.

Following, we can see the first tab (with the name and column to sum) and the second one (with the name and the roles.

First Tab: workload for employees per week
[workload for employees per week](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rD2Oa.png)

Second tab: roles per employee per week
[roles per employee per week](https://i.stack.imgur.com/85rXI.png)

Third Tab: Place to insert the result
[Place to insert the result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/c5wFk.png)

So, for example, I would like to `sumif` the first week for 'Socio' People: 30

I've tried a `sumif` with `filter` inside, `query`, `vlookup`, but I couldn't get to a working function.

Any suggestions??

Comment: I don't know about all the other ways but in Excel an array formula is pretty easy:  Put `=SUM(Time!H2:L5*(Time!H1:L1=DATE(2019,6,24))*(Roles!H2:L5="Eng 1."))` in a cell and press Control-Shift-Enter.  Then the formula will display with braces like `{=SUM(Time!H2:L5*(Time!H1:L1=DATE(2019,6,24))*(Roles!H2:L5="Eng 1."))}`  If you just press Enter on an array formula the calculated value will display `#VALUE!`

Comment: are you using google sheets or excel?

Answer (score 0):

### On Google Sheets:

You place the following formula in your first tab, assuming your second tab is called `Roles`:

```
=QUERY({'Roles'!G1:H5,G1:H5},"select Col2, SUM(Col5) group by Col2 label Col2 'Role', SUM(Col5) 'Totals'")
```

*You can expand it to use more columns (weeks)*.

Comment: As I'm not able to post answers, I've edited the question.

Answer (score 0):

try:

```
=SUM(FILTER(INDIRECT(
 ADDRESS(3,         MATCH(J2, A$2:E$2, 0), 4)&":"&
 ADDRESS(ROWS(A:A), MATCH(J2, A$2:E$2, 0), 4)), INDIRECT(
 ADDRESS(3,         MATCH(J2, F$2:I$2, 0)+5, 4)&":"&
 ADDRESS(ROWS(A:A), MATCH(J2, F$2:I$2, 0)+5, 4))=K2))
```

[image: 0]

### [spreadsheet demo](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1Yf0sVdLI6tVmHnnx5Xyo61uAYjZav07NhvCJSz4IlG8/edit#gid=1817111798)

Comment: as I am not able to post answers, I've edited the question.
Thanks for your help

Comment: can you share a copy of your sheet?

Comment: Sure:
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1yrdi2RcsaCHb30YUajDtENwmKL7ifoeOpFxueISURE0/edit?usp=sharing
----- Tab1 -> Alocação pessoas/projetos; ----
----- Tab2 -> Horas/Pessoas (section 'Cargos')
----- Tab3 -> Consolidação de dados (section 'Capacidade Produtiva')

Comment: please try again
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1yrdi2RcsaCHb30YUajDtENwmKL7ifoeOpFxueISURE0/edit?usp=sharing